# How to find a particular key in list of dictionary objects in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

i have query.oderby which is a list of dict objects.

```
[{'name': 'asc'}, {'user_id': 'desc'}]
```

I check if the list has user_id with the following

```
for query in query.orderby:
    if query.keys().__contains__('user_id'):
        if query['user_id'] == 'desc':
            #then sort in desc order
        elif query['user_id'] == 'asc':
            #the sort in asc order
        else:
            #move to next dict object
            query = query + 1

    else:
        #do something else if no user_id found in the list of dict
```

How can i check for user_id otherwise without using **contains**() and using the for loop?
I tried

```
if query.keys() == 'user_id':
    #then do something
```

But this didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use something like this if u want ur code to look simple.

```
l = [{'name': 'asc'}, {'user_id': 'desc'}]

for query in l:
   if (query.has_key('user_id')):
       print "Key Found"
```

Comment: Thanks that helped. How can i skip to the next dict object incase query['user_id'] is not 'asc' or 'desc'? In my case i just use query = query + 1. Is there any alternative?

Comment: I think I didnt quite get what u said. Are you trying to say tht you also want to check the value of query['user_id'] ?

Comment: @sanjana  If you are asking how to iterate to the next dict element in list, you dont have to worry about incrementing, as the for loop will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this :

```
>>> ar = [{'name': 'asc'}, {'user_id': 'desc'}]
>>> any('user_id' in elt for elt in ar)
True
```

You can find more informations regarding `any()` [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#any).

Hope it'll be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for answering.But i think my question wasn't very clear. I have modified the question. Please let me know what i can try.

Answer (score 0):

without for loop..

```
any(map((lambda x: True if 'user_id' in x.keys() else False ), ar ))
```